# Is there a generic git "undo" command?

Tags: git

Looking at some of the most popular questions ever asked on SO, it seems undoing git mistakes is a pretty common problem. Those questions are all well answered and the git commands themselves are fairly concise, but I was wondering if git has - or plans  on implementing in upcoming releases - a generic **git undo** command. This command would literally undo exactly whatever git command you most recently executed.

**Edit**: Just for specificity, what I mean is that git undo looks at the state of the repository right before you typed your mistaken command, and brings it back to an exact copy of what that state was

For example, if I did a **git add --all**, then typed something like **git undo**, git would unstage all the files that were just staged and the repository would look identical to what it had before I typed my git add all.

Also, here's a great [resource summarizing undoing git commands](https://github.com/blog/2019-how-to-undo-almost-anything-with-git)

Comment: @tbodt Agreed, I think I might try and build it this week :D

Comment: You could make this by creating a command called `git-undo`, which git would invoke when you type `git undo`.

Comment: No. No. NO. The Git project is certainly complex enough, and this is a classic example of feature creep

Comment: Kind of a good idea. I like it.

Comment: See my comment to trencl. I'm not proposing a new feature here. I'm asking what I'm sure many have wondered before...the "oh shit, I didn't mean to do that git command, can I effectively undo like I do in a text editor to the last state I was in". Even if the answer is obvious to some here, many might wonder if this exists. I know if I was first learning git I would look up such a command

Comment: While it's certainly true that (just about) anything you do in `git` can be undone, there is no generic undo feature, not least because in order for there to be one, either `git` would have to keep a precise record of everything you do in some sort of audit log, and `git undo` would have to know the exact opposite thing for every possible log entry, or the `git` object database would have to become fully transactional with robust rollback characteristics. Neither prospect is particularly easy to do...

Comment: Agree with @twalberg and if you'd want to be able to undo commands that affect remote systems such as `git push` it would become an order of magnitude harder, or not even practically possible. What if someone pulled your changes before you did undo, for example?

Answer (score 3):

**No, there is no such feature.** And as far as I can tell nobody has proposed to add it, either.

There's not really any documentation I can quote to prove the *non*-existence of this feature, and Stack Overflow is not the place to discuss or propose software features, so I will leave it at that.

Comment: I'm not proposing a new feature, I'm just writing that to suggest the intention of the command. And I edited it so that it didn't seem so poorly defined...it literally just brings the state of the repository back to the state it was in before you typed the command. I'm sure I'm not the first person to wonder if there was a command they could type after accidentally typing a git command and just wanting to undo what I had just typed, so I think it's valuable for people to at least know if it exists from SO. A newbie git person might certainly look this question up, as well as advanced

Comment: When I answered the question it definitely read (to me) more like a thinly veiled feature request than an actual question, but your edits have improved it. I have removed the "poorly defined" portion.

Comment: It might be helpful to check the files before commiting them automatically, (in the particular case of git add _), perhaps this tool could be useful to somebody, I don't know if it's relevant here though: https://github.com/dataf3l/g , but i've found this approach to help insert less mistakes into the repositories (full disclaimer, I wrote the tool, sorry for the blatant self-promotion)

Answer (score 2):

It would be pretty easy to make such a command yourself.

```
export STORE=/home/me/.git_backup 
mkdir $STORE
export ROOT=/home/me/src/somegitrepos
alias git='tar czf /$STORE/state.tar.gz -C $ROOT . ; /usr/bin/git'
alias git-undo='rm -rf $ROOT/* $ROOT/.??* ; cd $ROOT/ ; tar xzf /$STORE/state.tar.gz'
```

(Obviously, robustness needs to be added; i.e. making sure `$STORE/state.tar.gz` actually exists before the `rm -rf`, and supporting multiple different repositories etc.)

Of course, this is just a proof of concept. For larger repositories, the solution would be irritating. In this case, use a snapshotting filesystem and just do a snapshot in your `git` alias instead, and store the name of the snapshot instead of a full `tar.gz` archive. Pretty simple, and in a good FS (xfs for example) it would be absolute neglectable in terms of speed and space usage. You could even, trivially, have multi-step undo...

The solution is dead simple, so it would be utter madness to implement a "complex" version inside git itself which would be able to actually track all kinds of changes just to make space usage a bit more optimal (compared to snapshots, not the `tar` "solution").

By the way, there are at least two reasons why there is not built-in `git undo`:

- It would be a "horizontal" feature, i.e., every last `git` command which is not read-only (e.g., `status`, `log`) would have to be touched. Also, every single future command would need to include support for this. There may or may not be commands where it is simply impossible to do it (without falling back to a stupid `tar` solution like suggested here).
- After many years of experience with cvs, svn and git, I find that git seems very, very resistant against data loss. I'm not talking about bugs, but using git commands to "break" something. Except for a few commands like `git reset --hard` which modify files outside of the git store (i.e., your unadded changes in the working directory), literally everything is recoverable in a pretty easy way (until the garbage collection removes stuff...).

  The data storage scheme of git is also very simple to understand and to "see" for the normal user (heck, `gitk` and you're done). This is very different from my experience with those other tools, I absolutely dreaded complex merges in `svn`... So when you know how to undo stuff, the "need" for a `git undo` kind of vanishes.

  Powerful tools like `git rebase -i` or the simple fact that branches are just "sticky notes" let you recover from almost anything pretty easily (like, somehow merging a rebased branch where you merged the original branch already and whatever stupid stuff can happen in practice ;) ).

Comment: This wouldn't be able to undo changes that affected a remote system, such as a `git push`.